# Unable to find DEFAULT_INSTANCE when query datastore in dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-datastore, protocol-buffers

I am basically just follow the [word count example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/cookbook/DatastoreWordCount.java) to pull data from datastore in dataflow like

```
DatastoreV1.Query.Builder q = DatastoreV1.Query.newBuilder();
    q.addKindBuilder().setName([entity kind]);
    DatastoreV1.Query query = q.build();

    DatastoreIO.Source source = DatastoreIO.source()
            .withDataset([...])
            .withQuery(query)
            .withNamespace([...]);

    PCollection<DatastoreV1.Entity> collection = pipeline.apply(Read.from(source));
```

But it keeps failing on:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find DEFAULT_INSTANCE in com.google.api.services.datastore.DatastoreV1$Query at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$SerializedForm.readResolve(GeneratedMessageLite.java:1065) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at ...

Couldn't find any solution that seems relevant in the internet so far.

Might somebody could suggest maybe a general direction on what might be going wrong?

Comment: i am using `com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0` for protobuf btw

Comment: Which version of `com.google.apis:google-api-services-datastore-protobuf` are you using? It [recently](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#v1beta2-rev1-400) switched protocol buffer compiler versions from 2.5.0 to 3.0.0b1.

Comment: @EdDavisson oh i was using `com.google.apis:google-api-services-datastore-protobuf:v1beta2-rev1-2.1.2`

Comment: have tried protobuf compiler to 3.0.0 but seems not working... btw its seems that  3.0.0b1 is getting rid of all `DatastoreV1` library which i am currently using it somewhere else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protocol Buffers have certain restrictions. Among others, you have to link in the `protobuf` Java runtime that matches the version of the `protoc` compiler that the code was generated with, and you can (normally) have only one runtime present. This applies to all use cases of Protocol Buffers, and they aren't Dataflow specific.

Dataflow SDK for Java, version 1.4.0 and older, depends on `protobuf` version 2.5 and links in a Datastore client library generated with the corresponding `protoc` compiler. The easiest solution is not to override any `protobuf-java` and `google-api-services-datastore-protobuf` dependencies and let them be brought into your project by the Dataflow SDK.

If you really have to upgrade to `protobuf` version 3 for an unrelated reason, you should also upgrade `google-api-services-datastore-protobuf` to version `v1beta2-rev1-4.0.0`, because that one was generated with the corresponding `protoc` compiler. Please note that this is a *workaround* for Datastore only -- I would expect other dependencies that require `protobuf` version 2 to break, unless they are upgraded too.

Now, we are actively working on upgrading the Dataflow SDK to `protobuf` version 3. I'd expect this functionality in the next minor release, possibly 1.5.0. Since any version of the Dataflow SDK can support only one `protobuf` at a time, support for version 2 will break at that time, unless a few dependencies are manually rolled back.

Comment: Hi want to make sure it there any required versions for `google-api-services-datastore-protobuf` if i just stick to `protobuf-java` version 2.5 and `dataflow-1.1.0`?

Comment: i degrade my `protobuf-java` to 2.5 and has get rid of the `DEFAULT_INSTANCE` problem but not i am getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.services.datastore.client.QuerySplitter.getSplits(Lcom/google/api/services/datastore/DatastoreV1$Query;Lcom/google/api/services/datastore/DatastoreV1$PartitionId;ILcom/google/api/services/datastore/client/Datastore;)Ljava/util/List` and i am wondering whether that is also a problem of compile version mismatch

Comment: If you want to use Protobuf 2.5, just use any Dataflow SDK version 1.4.0 or earlier. Don't override any dependencies and things should be working out of the box.